# Collect logs for a function in python using shell script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have `pyspark` script that is working fine. This script will fetch data from mysql and create hive tables in `HDFS`.

The `pyspark` script is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

#Condition to specify exact number of arguments in the spark-submit command line
if len(sys.argv) != 8:
    print "Invalid number of args......"
    print "Usage: spark-submit import.py Arguments"
    exit()
table = sys.argv[1]
hivedb = sys.argv[2]
domain = sys.argv[3]
port=sys.argv[4]
mysqldb=sys.argv[5]
username=sys.argv[6]
password=sys.argv[7]

df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "{}:{}/{}".format(domain,port,mysqldb)).option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable","{}".format(table)).option("user", "{}".format(username)).option("password", "{}".format(password)).load()

#Register dataframe as table
df.registerTempTable("mytempTable")

# create hive table from temp table:
sqlContext.sql("create table {}.{} as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))

sc.stop()
```

Now this `pyspark` script will be invoked by using a `shell` script. For this shell script I am passing table names as arguments from a file.

The `shell script` is below.

```
#!/bin/bash

source /home/$USER/spark/source.sh
[ $# -ne 1 ] && { echo "Usage : $0 table ";exit 1; }

args_file=$1

TIMESTAMP=`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
touch /home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log
success_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.success_log
failed_logs=/home/$USER/logs/${TIMESTAMP}.fail_log

#Function to get the status of the job creation
function log_status
{
       status=$1
       message=$2
       if [ "$status" -ne 0 ]; then
                echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [ERROR] $message [Status] $status : failed" | tee -a "${failed_logs}"
                #echo "Please find the attached log file for more details"
                exit 1
                else
                    echo "`date +\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\"` [INFO] $message [Status] $status : success" | tee -a "${success_logs}"
                fi
}
while read -r table ;do 
  spark-submit --name "${table}" --master "yarn-client" --num-executors 2 --executor-memory 6g  --executor-cores 1 --conf "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=609" /home/$USER/spark/sql_spark.py ${table} ${hivedb} ${domain} ${port} ${mysqldb} ${username} ${password} > /tmp/logging/${table}.log 2>&1
  g_STATUS=$?
  log_status $g_STATUS "Spark job ${table} Execution"
done < "${args_file}"

echo "************************************************************************************************************************************************************************"
```

I am able to collect logs for each individual table in the args_file using the above shell script.

Now I have more than 200 tables in mysql. I have modified the `pyspark` script like below. I have create a function to itreate over the `args_file` and execute the code.

`New spark script`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
conf = SparkConf()
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)

#Condition to specify exact number of arguments in the spark-submit command line
if len(sys.argv) != 8:
    print "Invalid number of args......"
    print "Usage: spark-submit import.py Arguments"
    exit()
args_file = sys.argv[1]
hivedb = sys.argv[2]
domain = sys.argv[3]
port=sys.argv[4]
mysqldb=sys.argv[5]
username=sys.argv[6]
password=sys.argv[7]

def testing(table, hivedb, domain, port, mysqldb, username, password):

    print "*********************************************************table = {} ***************************".format(table)
    df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "{}:{}/{}".format(domain,port,mysqldb)).option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable","{}".format(table)).option("user", "{}".format(username)).option("password", "{}".format(password)).load()

    #Register dataframe as table
    df.registerTempTable("mytempTable")

    # create hive table from temp table:
    sqlContext.sql("create table {}.{} stored as parquet as select * from mytempTable".format(hivedb,table))

input = sc.textFile('/user/XXXXXXX/spark_args/%s' %args_file).collect()

for table in input:
 testing(table, hivedb, domain, port, mysqldb, username, password)

sc.stop()
```

Now I want to collect the logs for individual table in `args_file`. But I am getting only one log file that has the log for all the tables.

How can I achieve my requirement? Or is the method I am doing is completely wrong

> New shell script:

```
spark-submit --name "${args_file}" --master "yarn-client" --num-executors 2 --executor-memory 6g  --executor-cores 1 --conf "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=609" /home/$USER/spark/sql_spark.py ${table} ${hivedb} ${domain} ${port} ${mysqldb} ${username} ${password} > /tmp/logging/${args_file}.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Are you still using the bash script to call the python spark one?

Comment: @sal yes I am still using the same shell script

Comment: @sal please let me know if I need to do things differently

Comment: From what I see, now you have double loop over the tables: the shell script loops for each table and creates one log for each time the python script gets to run; but then, the python script will run against each table. If I am correct then you have several logfiles, each with all the logs inside.

Comment: @sal Actually I am getting only one file which contains log of all the tables. I want separate log files for each table in the args_file

Comment: @sal please have a look at the edited question which will be included in the new shell script

Comment: Ok, the point remains that, if you perform the logging in the shell script, but run the loop inside the python script, you are only going to get one logfile. Now, you could do two things: (1) go back to call the python script with different tables from the shell script (2) learn how to do logging or at the very list print to file from within the python script function testing. There is plenty of examples for (2) and (1) you already had working. Hope this takes you to the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is write a `python` script that will take a single log file and cut the log file a line before it `prints` the `table` name.

For example:

```
*************************************table=table1***************
```

Then the next log file starts from

```
*************************************table=table2****************
```

and so on. You can also have the table names as your file names